# Как в Pandas из значений списка вычленить уникальные(в значениях разделитель запятая)?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Пробую через Pandas. В таблице Excel есть столбец с индексами моторов df['Engine'],  в одной ячейке может быть 5-6 моторов разделённые запятой. Часть из значений может повторятся в различных ячейках. Я получаю список из значений в ячейках и делаю все значения уникальными, но как сделать такой список, чтобы 1 значение списка — 1 мотор? По сути у меня первое значение в ячейке '1AZ', а второе — '1AZ, 2AZ, 2AZFSE'. Я хочу получить список '1AZ','2AZ','2AZFSE'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
col_engine_list = df['Engine'].tolist()

engine_list_clean=[]
for engine in col_engine_list:
    if engine not in engine_list_clean:
        engine_list_clean.append(engine)

print(engine_list_clean)
# результат:
['nan', 'D13B, D15B, D16A, EJ18, 1NZFNE,1NZFXE,GA13DE, GA15DE, GA15E, VG30DE, VG30DET, MA10-T, MR16DDT', 'B5, B3, B1, B5,', '1KD-FTV', '4BC2', '5L', '1GR', '3S,3SFE,3SFSE,4SFE,4SFI,5SFE', '1NZ,1NZFE,1NZFNE,1NZFXE,2NZ,2NZFE', '1AZFSE,2AZFE', '1A,2A,3A,2A-U', 'L18,L18S,L13,L14,L16'.......итд] #список большой
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, понял, что задал некорректно.

Comment: Мне на выходе нужно получить список и уже дальше с ним работать. Я пробую это в образовательных целях, так как в самом экселе я знаю как это сделать.  У меня есть engine_list["D13B, D15B, D16A", "EJ18, MR16DDT",''MR16DDT", "B5, B3, B1", "1KD-FTV", "4BC2", "5L","1NZ,1NZFE","1GR", "3S,3SFE,3SFSE,4SFE,4SFI,5SFE", "1NZ,1NZFE,1NZFNE,1NZFXE"],  хочу получить engine_list_new["D13B", "D15B", "D16A", "EJ18", "MR16DDT", "B5", B3", "B1", "1KD-FTV", "4BC2", "5L", "1GR", "3S","3SFE","3SFSE","4SFE","4SFI","5SFE", "1NZ","1NZFE","1NZFNE","1NZFXE"]

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Если хотите получить более подробный и проверенный ответ - приведите в теле вопроса __воспроизводимый__ пример данных ;)

Comment: вообще ничего не ясно, что должно быть и что хотите.